# How to find images in a specific folder with a size not multiple of 2?

Tags: python, image-size, mipmaps

I've some folders with about 200 images and I'd like to highlight the images with a size not multiple of 2.

Is there an efficient way of doing so?

Best Regards!

Comment: What does it mean for an image to be a multiple of 2?

Comment: You can match all filenames, and then open with an image library and find the dimensions, and print those which are multiples of 2.

Comment: khelwood, I mean 2x2, 4x4, 8x8, ... 256 x 256 and variations as 64 x 128 ,

If an image is for instance, 127x63, I'd like to see it highlighted so that I can fix the mistake.


Thanks for the answer Peter wood, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Python script that print all images that have a size which is not a multiple of 2. It simply finds all images and use PIL to get the dimension.

```
import glob
from PIL import Image

# Get all images
image_path = 'PATH TO YOUR IMAGES'
images = glob.glob(image_path + '/**.png')  # Depending on your images extension
images_not_pair = []

# For all images open them with PIL and get the image size
for image in images:
    with Image.open(image) as im:
        width, height = im.size
        if width % 2 is not 0 or height % 2 is not 0:
            images_not_pair.append(image)

print(images_not_pair)
```

Comment: cyprieng, that you very much! 

It is far beyound what i can code currently, so I'm trying to understand each line.

I can't thank you enough!

Best regards!